# Update user email in custom module : validation API returns "Your current password is missing or incorrect"

Tags: 8, users

Users can update their email and user name in a form (Form API) in a custom module. The reason is it also updates an external service.

It works well but I’ve noticed an error during our test if a user enter an existing email (which is forbidden).

So I’ve added a validation `$user->validate()`

Now, I have this error message :

> Your current password is missing or incorrect; it's required to change
> the email/.

I don’t know how to proceed. Should I retrieve the user password  and send it again `$user->setPassword($password);` ? I've search on SO, Drupal Doc, etc. but I didn't find the correct way to do this.

Here is my code :

```
$uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();

// Get user storage object.
$user_storage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('user');

// Load user by their user ID
$user = $user_storage->load($uid);


 /**
 * Validation API
 * https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/entity-validation-api-overview
 */
 
  // Update email
  $user->setEmail($new_email);

  // Update username
  $user->setUsername($new_email);

  $violations_user = $user->validate();
  if ($violations_user->count() > 0) {
       $violation = $violations_user[0];
       drupal_set_message($violation->getMessage(), 'warning');
       // Here is the message "Your current password is missing or incorrect"
  } else {

      $user->save();
  }
```

Comment: Just to add use entityTypeManager instead of entityManager

Comment: @miststudent2011Can you explain what you mean by use `entityTypeManager` instead of `entityManager` ? Why should I do this ? Thanks.

Comment: @Sebasstien entityManager is deprecated and replaced with entityTypeManager https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2782833 , I can not find the exact change record but the url is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The violations you're seeing come from core's [`ProtectedUserFieldConstraint`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Plugin%21Validation%21Constraint%21ProtectedUserFieldConstraint.php/class/ProtectedUserFieldConstraint/9.0.x). The constraint is applied when the current user tries to update their account fields without supplying a password. The [validator method](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Plugin%21Validation%21Constraint%21ProtectedUserFieldConstraintValidator.php/function/ProtectedUserFieldConstraintValidator%3A%3Avalidate/9.0.x) has a built-in flag to disable this check when needed (e.g. when a user resets their password).

To set the flag, set the `_skipProtectedUserFieldConstraint` to `TRUE` (e.g. `$user->_skipProtectedUserFieldConstraint = TRUE;`) and the validator won't enforce supplying a password when changing the current user fields.